# auto download zip files script

Tags: php

I want to write a script that will download zip files from a given url and save it somewhere in my hard disk. URL looks like this. http://localhost/downloads/1 to http://localhost/downloads/1. I am trying it like this

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
    $zipfile=file_get_contents('http://localhost/downloads'.$i);
    echo $zipfile;}
```

but it won't work.
I wanted to try this script on localhost. id will be downloading songs, pics for me.

Comment: "`http://localhost/downloads/1` to `http://localhost/downloads/1`"...? Huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your URL are like `http://localhost1`, `http://localhost2`....Notice the missing `/`.

Also to save the downloaded content you use the function `file_put_contents` not `echo`. And this needs to be done inside the loop as:

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) {
   $zipfile=file_get_contents('http://localhost/downloads/'.$i);
   file_put_contents('some/other/dir/'.$i.'zip',$zipfile);
}
```

Since you're copying from `localhost` to `localhost` you can better use the [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function.